# Android launch Genymotion but not in device

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-manifest, genymotion

I´m having a trouble when I want to launch my app in a device with AndroidStudio (AS). If I launch it in Genymotion it works fine, but when I launch in my device, AS installs it but app doesn´t launch.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv.activities">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

        <!-- Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login Account" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name=".CenterTvSelection"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_center_tv_selection" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

My gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

LOG:

```
Launching application: com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv/com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv.activities.LoginActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv/com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv.activities.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv/.activities.LoginActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.twentyfit.twentyfitpublicidadtv/.activities.LoginActivity } from null (pid=11358, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10048
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1783)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:268)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you help me? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your manifest file, the first `<activity>`
tag does not close correctly. The intent-filter should be inside the activity tag, in your case it is not.

More precisely like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login Account">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```